# insert array into multiple rows into mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my var_dump($img);

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "1.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "2.PNG"
}
```

In the beginning I think I could use serialize but it only inserted one row.

```
if(!empty($img_src)){

    foreach ($img_src as $key => $value) {
    $targeted_post_id = $db->insert_id;

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO photo_upload(`post_id`,`img_src`) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $targeted_post_id,$value);
    $stmt->execute();

    }

}
```

Comment: And write the insert query inside the foreach

Answer (score 0):

Use code below

```
foreach($img as $k){

//Insert into database here. This will add all the records which are in array.

}
```

$k will have value `1.png` & `2.png` in each loop.

Comment: not working with prepare statement? I received a row although I have 2 items

Comment: why are you using 'is' in bind_param?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for Insert array value in Database one by one.

use `foreach` or `for` looping statement

for example.

```
  foreach($img as $key=>$image) {
         echo $image;
         //Insert query statement
  }
```

For looping Statement.

```
  $image = count($img);
   for($i=0;$i<=$image;$i++) {
         echo $img[$i];
        //Insert query statement
  }
```

You should insert single row means you can used `serialize()` function.

Comment: I use pdo and with looping I still inserting 1 row of result.         $stmt->bind_param('is', $post_id,$image);